# Folium markers with Pandas data. Why do no markers show up?

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial, folium

I am attempting to plot gun violence incidents in the U.S. from the kaggle data set on U.S. gun violence 2013-2018. With some research I found that folium is a good option for me. However, after many attempts and much googling, I cannot in any way get the markers to show up on the map (except for the initial one, and one more which persistently shows up further north than the initial one - I have no clue whether it represents an actual incident or it is some sort of bug).

The data set is a pandas df, and I made a subset it of it only including the longitude, latitude, incident_id and n_killed variables for this part of the process. Admittedly there are 250k incidents, so any and all plotting would take lots of time - but I am willing to wait if it works. I'm open to suggestion for other packages that are perhaps more suitable for this process. 
Here is my code as I have tried it thus far:

```
folium_map = folium.Map(location=[40.00, -73.00],
                    zoom_start=13,
                    tiles="CartoDB dark_matter")
marker = folium.CircleMarker(location=[40.738, -73.98])
marker.add_to(folium_map)
for index, row in gunviolence_try.iterrows():
if row['n_killed'] >2:
    color="#E37222" 
else:
    color="#0A8A9F"

folium.CircleMarker(location=(row["latitude"],      
                          row["longitude"]),
                color = color,
                fill=True).add_to(folium_map)
folium_map
```

Any and all pointers for how to go about this are really appreciated!

Comment: 250k is a lot for folium.  How long does it run before showing just the two points?

Comment: Not very long at all - less than a minute. After a while I became aware that 250k is not what folium was made for, but beyond that I'd expect it to crash, rather than just plot one random incident beyond the mapping coordinates. Is it advisable to drop folium, and if so, is there something you would reccomend?

Comment: Perhaps folium's [FastMarkerCluster](http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/docs-v0.5.0/plugins.html#folium.plugins.FastMarkerCluster) would work?

Comment: I will give it a shot. Does the code that I provide seem valid in that case, and folium's default marker simply cannot handle it?

Comment: Yes, your code seems to be in order other than the for-loop block not being indented.

Comment: Also, some times when working with larger datasets i'll save the map and then open it as opposed to displaying it in a juypter notebook

Comment: FastMarkerCluster works! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ok, right on.  Happy to help